# How to add product category wise commission in YITH MULTI VENDOR & YITH AFFILIATE

Tags: wordpress

I can set admin commission by product wise and vendor wise in YITH multi vendor plugin and able to set affiliate member commission by user wise and product wise.

But seller can not pay same commission on every product. Vendor will feel comfort with paying different commission percentage on different type of product.

So i want to set product category wise commission for Vendor "YITH MULTI VENDOR"  and  Affiliate "YITH AFFILIATE".

Comment: what have you tried so far? please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am noob in coding so my try are just joke.

Comment: Well, this is not how this site works. Questions are required to fit a Q&A Format. If you want your question to be answered, your best bet is to stick to those guidelilnes. Please make the [tour] and read [ask].